# java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate invokes thread every 4-5 seconds when configured for 12 hours

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a singleton class that creates a thread on instance creation. Only one object of this class is created and the thread is scheduled to run every 12 hours and print the given statement. In some cases after the first 12h the thread is invoked every 4-5 seconds.  I am confused as to why this happens as I have configured the scheduler to run once every 12 hours and not every 4-5 seconds. Is there any config I have missed or is the scheduler wrong configured?

the singleton class,

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadSchedulerTest {
private static final ThreadSchedulerTest test = new ThreadSchedulerTest();
private ThreadSchedulerTest (){createThread();}

private void createThread() {

        Runnable renewer = () -> {
            System.out.println("Running ok , time is : "+ Instant.now());
        };
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new 
 ThreadSchedulerThreadFactory("thread1")).scheduleAtFixedRate(
                renewer, 0, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS);

}
static class ThreadSchedulerThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private final String name;

    public ThreadSchedulerThreadFactory(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r, name);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
    }
}
}
```

Can someone please help clarify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it easier to test the if you change the TimeUnit to  SECONDS and make the Runnable print hashcode of the instance:

```
Runnable renewer = () -> {
    System.out.println("Running ok instance="+ThreadSchedulerTest.this.hashCode()+", time is : "+ Instant.now());
};
```

Your problem with repeating every 4-5 seconds is probably that you have created two instances of ThreadSchedulerTest. The above message fix will confirm.

The code you have provided will not run as you have recursive definition of the constructor and member variable. Thus every instance of `ThreadSchedulerTest` executes second constructor `ThreadSchedulerTest test = new ThreadSchedulerTest();` - which then instantiates a new member `test`:

```
new ThreadSchedulerTest()
|  Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError
|        at ThreadSchedulerTest.<init> (#5:2)
```

You can fix my making this declaration - `test` is static and constructor private so only one instance is ever constructed:

```
public class ThreadSchedulerTest {
   static final ThreadSchedulerTest test = new ThreadSchedulerTest();
   private ThreadSchedulerTest () {
        createThread(); 
   }
   ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.. seems I have missed a few keywords when editing the question.. I do have a private constructor and test object is also static and final. The issue still persists.. Also like I have mentioned in the question this comes up only few times and at other times it runs perfectly fine. I am unable to find at what exact case the scheduler starts scheduling frequently and not at the given period.

Comment: Add the `main` too if self contained program. If not, and you are using app server or web container, restart it between deploys as you are seeing old and new instances of the class running.

Comment: I restart the app almost every week and during deployments, this issue comes up sometimes and does not appear at times. Any idea on how to be certain that I have old instances of the class running? I have tried logging the thread id too, its the same thread that executes frequently.

Comment: You already have proof that 2 instances are running. If you use hot-deploy inside app server or web container you would need to handle graceful close/cleanup of the executor services related to the previous deployment using whatever mechanism your container service provides (eg ServletContentListener for servlet containers).